# Eigenvalue of product of a matrix with a non negative matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, singular-values

Acording to [this](http://math.ucr.edu/~jdolan/schubert2.pdf)[image]

Now in my case, I have A=-LB, where L is a Laplacian matrix of an undirected graph. Hence L is a nonnegative matrix.

Since the maximum singular value of (-L) is 0, can I conclude based on the above result, that maximum singular value of A is also 0?

Comment: The singular values are nonnegative numbers. If the maximum singular value of a matrix is zero, all singular values are zero. This is true if and only if the matrix is a zero matrix.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. Now I understand that the mistake I did was by assuming 0 as the maximum singular value. Actually, 0 is the minimum singular value.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot more sense. In this case the above theorem is not helpful. However, you can still show that the minimum singular value of $A$ is zero as well (as the product of rank-deficient matrices is rank-deficient as well).

Comment: @Florian Actually I am looking for eigenvalues, and to show that the minimum eigenvalue of A is 0, I can use the property of determinants that det(AB)=detA)det(B) and det(A)=0 since one of its eigenvalues is 0.

Comment: Absolutely. That is what I meant actually. :)